# Mean value theorem for integrals, variant:

Tags: definite-integrals

I am trying to prove the following:

Suppose $\phi:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous, bounded and integrable function and $\psi:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous, bounded above by 1, strictly decreasing, positive function.

Then, there exists a $\xi \in [0,\infty)$ such that $\int_0^{\infty} \psi(x)\phi(x)dx = \psi(\xi)\int_0^{\infty}\phi(x)dx$

I was able to show that there exists $\xi$ such that $\mid \int_0^{\infty} \psi(x)\phi(x)dx \mid  = \psi(\xi)\int_0^{\infty}\mid \phi(x) \mid dx$ using the inequality $\mid\int_0^{\infty} \phi(x) dx \mid < \int_0^{\infty}\mid \phi(x)\mid dx$ and the intermediate value theorem. Any ideas how to proceed from here?

Comment: Are you sure $\psi$ is positive and not $\phi$? The positive one should be the one staying in the integral.

Comment: Yes, i think this is what makes it different to the mean value theorem. I have tried it with a few examples and it seems to hold but i can't come up with a general proof!

Comment: Uh, ok, then the proof I had in mind won't work :)

Comment: I think the proof you had in mind is exactly what i said i was able to show !:)